# Python Lambda function optional variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

```
substring = lambda s,start=0,end=len(s) : s[start:end]
print(substring("python",1))
```

I get an error saying s is not defined

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7e4b2c9c6d67> in <module>()
----> 1 substring = lambda s,start=0,end=len(s) : s[start:end]
      2 print(substring("python",1,3))

 NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

I want to give the start and end as optional variables. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't do that in the definition; you can't in a regular function, either. You'd have to do something like `s[start or 0:end or len(s)]`. But as a rule of thumb: if you're naming the `lambda`, just write a function.

Comment: Thanks! Okay.. I will try that way. (I am beginner, will keep in mind the rule)